# WCF Service calling another WCF Service is slow

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a design whereby we have a WCF Service that accesses a datastore that is represented as another WCF service. The idea behind this is to adhere to the SOA and have the potential to load balance by the actual service and the data access layer, as well as enable the datastore to change massively with no impact on the initial service.

Problem is these are running on IIS6 and encryption must be enabled.

With both services enabled we are getting averages of approximately

Average Number of requests per second: 4.75469280423686 over 400 calls.

But if I remove the service call to the second service and replace with an absolute reference this nearly doubles to

Average Number of requests per second: 8.52248037501811 over 400 calls.

Does anyone have any clues as to how/what I can do to optimise this?

I should add these are not concurrent calls.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing a similar issue and it's being extremely difficult to track down the source.

Answer (score 0):

Are both web services running on the same machine and the same app pool?  I've had that exact issue before; we eventually cut that architecture completely, but I believe it could have been helped by putting them in different app pools.

Also, since you mentioned IIS6, .Net may be holding back on you: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx (Chapter 6: Improving ASP.NET Performance) - especially the "Threading Explained" section.  (IIS6 by default doesn't have the appropriate number of .Net threads for your processor - IIS7+ does.)

Good luck!

Comment: They are very much running in the same app pool.. I will try that. at this time threading hasn't even come into it all my tests are 400 consecutive requires where there is a 1:1 mapping of requests to S1->S2

Comment: Interesting, it sounds like there's a lag in each connection to IIS, even from within itself.  Do you have a service behavior that's taking some amount of time, such as authenticating in a SOAP header?